# Preventing a FloatingActionButton from scrolling within ViewPager

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a ViewPager where one of its pages has a FloatingActionButton. The toolbar uses a CoordinatorLayout with `scroll|enterAlways`, so it disappears as the user scrolls.

This causes the FloatingActionButton to be initially invisible and scroll into view as the user scrolls and the toolbar disappears.

The intent is to have the FAB fixed on the screen at all times. One hacky idea would be to move it into the layout that contains the ViewPager, but I only want it to be on one page.

Here is the top-level layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:id="@+id/new_toolbar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/vp_main"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Pretty straightforward - a toolbar that scrolls out of sight (and immediately comes back in when scrolling up), and a view pager.

Here is the relevant layout for the ViewPager's page:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_48dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        android:id="@+id/add" />
</FrameLayout>
```

I tried some random silliness like `app:layout_scrollFlags=""` and `app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.Behavior"`, but none of those helped - I guess the problem is that the size of the FrameLayout covers the full screen without the toolbar. What's the best way to solve this?

Comment: Put the FAB outside of the view pager. Ask for it in view pager fragments via callback or dependency injection. Show/hide it or change its appearance based on current fragment.

Comment: @EugenPechanec definitely a viable option. I'm hoping for something else because I don't want the logic for the FAB to spread outside the page, but unless somebody has a smarter idea, that's what I'm gonna have to go with.

Comment: I know your pain, had the same problem. If you look at the specs, FAB always stays in one place and morphs the background and image according to changing fragments. It's not what happens in Google Maps though (there are multiple FABs) so it really depends on individual needs.

Comment: @EugenPechanec Bah, I guess this simply is the way to go, and I ended up implementing it that way. Feel free to write a proper answer to this so I can throw 25 points at you!

Answer (score 0):

A year late but perhaps it would help others who are looking for an answer on this.

You should move the FAB declaration into the CoordinatorLayout below the ViewPager, like you proposed. Then, on your main activity class, add an `OnPageChangeListener` to your ViewPager instance, within the `onCreate` method.

For example:

```
fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.add);
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        //positions 0, 1, 2 = first tab, second tab, third tab respectively            
        if (position == 0 && positionOffset == 0)
            fab.show();
        else
            fab.hide();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
});
```